# Redirect with react router / retrieve state from parent?

Tags: reactjs

First page:

```
   const firstpage= () => {
         //some code above here..
         //then
        history.push({
        pathname: '/cars', 
        state: {
             cars: [cars.data],
         }
        //Redirect to cars page with the state
       })   
    }
```

Then I redirect it to /cars with the state.

Cars page:

```
import { Link , Redirect, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

const Cars = () => {
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log(state.cars);
    // Works fine and able to retrieve the data
}
```

However, I don't want the users to go to /cars without any state from being set in the first page.

How can I make sure so a user with empty state from cars, will not go to url/cars

Maybe some function similar to "if logged in"?

```
const App  = () => {
   // Can I retrieve something from useLocation like the cars page?
   // Problem may be that the state has never been pushed

  const CarsNotSet= () => {
      return <Redirect to="/" />
  };

  return (
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
         <Firstpage/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cars">
         <Cars/>
        </Route>

        <Route path="" component={CarsNotSet} />

      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already solved the issue. with `useLocation`
Just check the `state.cars` using `useEffect`
**Cars.js:**

```
const { state } = useLocation();
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (!state.cars) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }
}, [])
```

Dont't forget to import useEffect from react:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
```

Comment: Yes, But I want to work with the routes. I want to remove the Route if the props/state is empty. I just wonder how I can retrive it through App..

Comment: You can use [react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) because you need to update the state from first page component while your routes exists inside **App.js**. Update the store in **first page** set cars to `cars.data`, then you need to check if cars is set in **App.js** `const car = useSelector(state => state.cars)` then `{cars ** <Route path="/cars"><Cars/></Route>}`